# Resize a dd dump without changing partition size

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, images

First of all, apologies if this has been asked before. I found a lot of similar questions, but none that completely match my situation.

I have a raw disk image made from an ext4 partition on an Android device using dd -

```
busybox dd if=/dev/block/someblock of=backup.img
```

The source partition was large in size, but didn't have much data. So the image file has a lot of unused space.

I need to reduce the file size of the image without resizing the filesystem partition. Is it possible to move the data to the beginning of the image and then truncate the file? If I do this, will I be able to write this image back to the original source later without resizing the partition? (I can completely wipe the target device before writing, if required).

If yes, how can I do this?

Compression is not an option. I need a raw file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up cat-ing the file to a temporary partition on an HDD; resizing the partition to the minimum size (adding free space to the right side) and then back to the initial size using GParted; and dd-ing the part of the partition which had data to a new file.